# EphemeralKey in .NET Stripe SDK does not have the field "secret" causing an error "Secret not found"

Tags: c#, android, .net, stripe-payments

I am creating a .NET c# back-end and following the instructions from the Stripe docs ([Stripe Docs](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android/basic?lang=dotnet))

However, in the .NET SDK the EphemeralKey class does not contain the "secret" field ([NET SDK EphemeralKey.cs](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/blob/master/src/Stripe.net/Entities/EphemeralKeys/EphemeralKey.cs))

How is it supposed to return the field that the Android SDK looks for ([Android SDK EphemeralKey.kt](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/blob/master/stripe/src/main/java/com/stripe/android/EphemeralKey.kt))  if it's not there ?

Stripe do have a sample app but that does not work with the .NET back end - same error.

I have successfully integrated Stripe.NET about 3 years ago but there seem to be some changes that have not been well integrated perhaps.

**EDIT:**
I have realised that the EphemeralKey.cs class needs that secret field. Thus I just branched the sdk code and added the field and everything works fine. But is that the best solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I found that you are supposed to use the RawJson field so I just need to have that field in my response model class.

I was not looking for it, because i was trying to use the SDK EphemeralKey class but that's not what that's for, since this is a response from your server not Stripe API

So I just need to parse the response for the RawJson field and then create a model class out of that, which will have the secret field in it